# Why don't I get output on OSX with this F# code but I do on Windows

Tags: macos, visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

I'm trying to execute the following F# script code on my `macbook pro` using `FSI` in `visual studio code` and the `ionide` plugin.

```
#r "packages/Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1/lib/net40/Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
#r "System.Net.Http"

open System
open System.Net.Http
open Newtonsoft.Json

let client = new HttpClient()

type AlbumInfo = { userId:int; id:int; title:string }

let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1"

async {
    let! res = Async.AwaitTask <| client.GetAsync(url)
    let! content = Async.AwaitTask <| res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    let  x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlbumInfo>(content)

    printfn "%s" x.title
} |> Async.Start

printfn "Please wait..."
```

But I don't get any output apart from `Please wait...`. However, when I put `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1` into the browser I get the expected `Json` response. So I know there's no problem reaching the API.

Also, when I run the same code in `Visual Studio 2013` on my `Windows 10` PC. The code produces the expected result. i.e. `Please wait...` and the `title` of the album.

Any ideas why it doesn't work correctly on my `macbook`?

Comment: What if you await the started `asnyc` after the `printfn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio there is a process hosting FSI and keeping the thread (pool) for the `async` computation alive. In FSI on the command line or VS Code, FSI will just terminate as soon as the main thread has finished writing `Please wait...` (which typically is before the computation was even started on the thread pool).

If you want to observe the side effects of an `async` computation you have to await its result (in this example `unit`):

```
let computation = async {
    printfn "Starting async"
    let! res = Async.AwaitTask <| client.GetAsync(url)
    let! content = Async.AwaitTask <| res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    let x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlbumInfo>(content)
    printfn "Downloaded %s" x.title
}

async {
    let! started = computation |> Async.StartChild
    let! _ = Async.Sleep 1 // only here to get interleaved ouput
    printfn "Please wait..."
    let! res = started
    printfn "Got result %A" res
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

will likely print:

> Starting async
>   Please wait...
>   Downloaded quidem molestiae enim
>   Got result <null>

Comment: Thanks @CaringDev. I haven't had a chance to try this on my ```macbook``` but I can confirm that my original code fails in the same way when using ```FSI``` at the command prompt as you suggested. Your example works correctly both in ```VS``` and ```FSI``` at the command prompt, therefore I'm sure it will work on my ```macbook``` also. Your explanation of ```VS``` keeping the thread (pool) alive make sense. Thank you very much for your help.